# microsoft sql - how select data with random sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have around 50k records in the table, I want to save all the records with random order and grouping into other table. eg: at the first run, system will select 10(random) records and insert into the 2nd table, at the second run, system will select 15(random) records and insert into the 2nd table & ... 
until all the records moved to 2nd table.
I tried to use `order by ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % XXX)`  to make the random order, but how can I make the grouping to control the minimum records & maximum records in the select query??

Comment: If you do this in batches this way you may select the same rows more than once. It also seems like an expansive operation, not one to do when the database is too busy. Can you write a program? It could select all ids in the table into a list. Then shuffle the list and copy the rows one by one in the shuffeled order.

Comment: I don't get it.  What is the grouping?  Why not just move all the records at once?  There is more to what you are trying to do than you have explained.

Answer (score 0):

user order by  NEWID() at the end

like

```
select * from table order by newid()
```

Comment: But be aware: performance WILL be terrible - it HAS to get all rows into a sorted list to find the first one. SQL and random order and high performance are not compatible.